# Convert array from indexed to simple string

Tags: php, arrays

I have an indexed array but I need to convert it in simple array just like below. hope you can help me.

This is my current array

```
Array
(
[0] => 4
[1] => 4
[2] => 0
[3] => 3
[4] => 3
```

)

But I need to convert it into like this.

```
array("4","4","0","3","4");
```

or much better if unique like this

```
array("4","4","0","3","4");
```

Thank you

Comment: Whether you realize it or not. They are all the same (after considering the weak type nature of PHP).

Comment: How is the third code part "unique" or different from the second?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand your request, I propose you to test this:

```
$array = [
    "0" => "4",
    "1" => "4",
    "2" => "0"
];

$string = "";

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $string = $string.$value;
}
```

It returns "440".

Hope it can help you

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
        $a = array("4", "4", "0", "3", "4");
        $str = 'array(';
        foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
            $str.='"' . $value . '",';
        }
        $str = trim($str, ',');
        $str.=')';
        echo $str;
```

Outpur: `array("4","4","0","3","4")`